# iframe onload fires when iframe is not ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

So I have a problem in vanilla React.
I have this line of code in the `ready()` function :

```
var current = this;    
React.createElement(
            "iframe",
            {id: "iframeController", 
             ref: "iframe", 
             src: "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(notification.description), 
             onLoad: current.iframeLoaded(this)}
)
```

the notification.description is from a maping that I do of an object in the `this.state.notifications`

and this function to follow it

```
iframeLoaded(iframe) {
    if(iframe) {
        iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";         
    }
}
```

However, if I console.log the (iframe) element in iframeLoaded, it returns as null. Same thing if I getElementById, except then it's undefined.

I did a setTimeout to see if its a component updating problem, and turns out it is. So the onLoad even in Chrome is firing before the src has the time to render.

I'm trying to get the height so that I can set it in a window, allowing it to resize and take the full height of the iframe that I'm getting.

Can anyone give my any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with this line: `onLoad: current.iframeLoaded(this)}`. In that context, `onLoad` is being set to the return value of `current.iframeLoaded(this)`.

I believe you want to wrap the value in a function (not an arrow notation, but a traditional function):

```
onLoad: function(){current.iframeLoaded(this);}}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thank you! I think you might be right, my brain is a bit slower than usual today

Comment: Still returns as unidentified sigh, the struggle is real today hehe

Comment: actually I tried with getElementById again using the wrapper function and it works. Now it just gives me a Blocked frame - cross origin exception, but thats fine ill deal with that. Thanks man!